# Language culture missing from url on post back

Tags: multilingual, link-manager

Language culture such as 'en' or 'en-gb' was initially present with a sitecore url. But after a post back, page returns with some validation errors and language culture is missing from url.

What may be the possible reason ?

I checked the link manager config. It is like below

```
 addAspxExtension="false" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false"
 encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="always"
 languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="true" 
 shortenUrls="false" useDisplayName="true"
 ignoreForSites="shell,login,admin" forceFriendlyUrl="true" 
 trailingSlash="false" onlyApplyForSiteContent="true" 
 resolve="true" previewSearchIndexName="sitecore_master_index" 
 liveSearchIndexName="sitecore_master_index"
```

Mind that `languageEmbedding` is true.

And the view is below

```
    @model ChangePasswordViewModel
@using Foundation.Dictionary.Extensions
@using Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Extensions
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post))

    @Html.AddUniqueFormId()
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName);
    <div class="form-horizontal my-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <label class="control-label">Change Password</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.OldPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-7">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-gradient-3" />
            </div>
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @if (ViewBag.ChangePasswordMessage != null)
                    {
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            @ViewBag.ChangePasswordMessage
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure the config is not patched by some other config file? Please navigate to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` page and check what is effective config there

Comment: We are using a patch file. I checked in the showconfig.aspx and languageEmbedding="always" there.

Comment: WebForms or MVC? Are you posting a custom form to a controller? Post up code of the form on the razor view

Comment: We are using MVC `@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post))
{`

Comment: I cant post the whole razor view because of size limitations. It has 3 text boxes for old password, new password, confirm new pass word with an update button

Comment: For all post back  we are facing this behaviour

Comment: Edit your post to include the Razor view. Don't try and put it in as a comment.

Comment: I have done that

Comment: @HrishikeshTT: Is this issue solved for you? If yes how did you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Html.BeginRouteForm, try using Html.BeginForm without any parameters like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    ....
}
```

This will set the action attribute of your form tag to the url of your current page.

Comment: It worked, when using Html.BeginForm language culture is appended to form tag's action attribute.What may be the possible differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places were the original setting for LinkManager can be overwritten:

### 1. By having a patch config file in your solution

Check whether you don't have `<linkManager>` element somewhere in your custom patch config files.

It should look something like this:

```
<linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="sitecore" ... languageEmbedding="never" ... />
    </providers>
</linkManager>
```

The languageEmbedding options are:

```
asNeeded
always
never
```

Changing the config to use languageEmbedding="never" will stop the language from showing up in the URL, and likewise languageEmbedding="always" will force the language to always show up in the URL.

Probably you have it set to `never`.

Check it also by navigating to `{your_sitecore_instance_url}/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` and how linkManager is configured effectively there.

### 2. By changing this setting for link itself in your code

You can override config settings from code when you are generating link.

Try to find similar code around code where LinkManager generates links in your question. It should be something similar:

```
var options = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions(); 
options.LanguageEmbedding = Sitecore.Links.LanguageEmbedding.Never; 
Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options);
```

Try to search for `LanguageEmbedding` and maybe you will be lucky

### (3.) languageEmbedding needs to be set

Make sure `languageEmbedding` is set to either `always` or `never`. Don't leave it set to `asNeeded` cause this could also cause you trouble! Learnt hard way...

Comment: I checked these, But LanguageEmbedding is no where set as Never

Comment: Is languageEmbedding set to Always or AsNeeded?

Comment: It is set to Always

Comment: We checked the scenario in habitat solution, there also it showing same behaviour.